# Disabling the datepicker updates the date in input

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

Given an `input`, I initialise a `datepicker` and all is well. Note, however, that the value in the `input` is outside the allowed date range in the `datepicker` initialisation. The behaviour is as I expect: date picker will allow the date to be changed to something in the allowed range.

Then, I set the `option "disabled"` on the `datepicker` and it updates the value in the `input` (to the maximum value allowed in the `datepicker` initialisation).

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/smrunjgm/4/

Is there a way to prevent `option "disabled"` from changing the value in the `input`?

Answer (score 0):

Call the on [blur](http://api.jquery.com/blur/) event on the input

```
$("#date1").blur(function() {
         $("#date1").datepicker( "option", "disabled", false);
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/smrunjgm/7/)